# Spring Security @PreAuthorize sets validator bean to null while adding it to WebDataBinder

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I am using `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`, but once I annotated any controller method with `@PreAuthorize` the bean validator bean becomes null when adding the validator to the data binder. and here is my code:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true) //to enable method level security


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/capacityDelegations")
public class CapacityDelegationController implements Serializable{


/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 6878225451248023554L;


private CapacityDelegationHandler capacityDelegationHandler;
private CapacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator;


public CapacityDelegationController(CapacityDelegationHandler capacityDelegationHandler, CapacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator) {
    // checked here in debug mode to make sure that validator's bean injected properly
    this.capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator = capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator; 
    this.capacityDelegationHandler = capacityDelegationHandler;

}

@InitBinder("capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequest")
private void initCapacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    //in debug mode when a PUT request received the value of capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator turns to null if @PreAuthorize applied and not null if removed
binder.addValidators(this.capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequestValidator); 
}



@PutMapping(path = "/serial={serial}/submission")
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_OFFICER')")
public ResponseEntity<?> submit(@Valid @RequestBody CapacityDelegationChangeStatusRequest capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequest) throws JudicialWarrantException {
    return capacityDelegationHandler.submit(null, capacityDelegationChangeStatusRequest);
}



}
```

I am using Spring boot 5.0.5